# Assigning permissions to System Settings File

Tags: android

I am trying to assign permission to a file i have created which is used to set the system Settings.I am getting an Io Exception on line

```
inputStream=context.getAssets().open(fileName);
```

In my manifest file i have assigned the file permission using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

which allows to read and write to system settings file.But still the Exception.Thanks in advance.
As per request I am adding the code where Error occurs

```
public boolean copyConfigFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        File configFile = new File(systemDir, fileName);
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Config file path :" + configFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "FILE NAME::" + fileName);
        if(!configFile.exists()){
            configFile.createNewFile();
            InputStream is = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            try {
                is = ctx.getAssets().open(fileName);
                os = new FileOutputStream(configFile);
                byte []fileBytes = new byte[is.available()];
                is.read(fileBytes);
                os.write(fileBytes);
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "File copied.");
                return true;
            } finally {
                if(is != null){
                    is.close();
                }
                if(os != null){
                    os.close();
                }
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "File already exist.");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. Found the mistake.The System Settings file that is created should be saved in the assets Directory and not anywhere Else.I was stupid to not read it before hand

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS ?

Or may be the path to file that is given wrong. You may need to post more specific code.

Comment: Well I have added 2 permissions more::<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  Still no result